# Normalized RMSE

Tags: time-series, mse, rms

I have several time-series in a VAR(1) and, due to some of them haven't the same unit of measure, I'd like to estimate the RMSE in percentage. 
I know that it could be done in several ways (see below) but I don't know precisely which is the one that fits better a forecast evaluation problem. I hope you could help me.

Examples of normalized RMSE:
$$
RMSE_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\left(\frac{Y_{forecast_i}-Y_i}{Y_i}\right)^2} \\
RMSE_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\left(\frac{Y_{forecast_i}-Y_i}{Y_{forecast_i}}\right)^2} \\
RMSE_3 = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\left(Y_{forecast_i}-Y_i\right)^2}}{mean(Y)}
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have also [other choices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131267/how-to-interpret-error-measures-in-weka-output/131273#131273) that are commonly used in such cases, e.g. relative absolute error

$$ \text{RAE} = \frac{ \sum^N_{i=1} | \hat{\theta}_i - \theta_i | } {  \sum^N_{i=1} | \overline{\theta} - \theta_i | } $$

root relative squared error

$$ \text{RRSE} = \sqrt{ \frac{ \sum^N_{i=1} \left( \hat{\theta}_i - \theta_i \right)^2 } {  \sum^N_{i=1} \left( \overline{\theta} - \theta_i \right)^2 }} $$

mean absolute percentage error

$$ \text{MAPE} = \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1} \left| \frac{\theta_i - \hat{\theta}_i}{\theta_i} \right| $$

where $\theta$ is true value, $\hat \theta$ is the forecast and $\overline{\theta}$ is a mean of $\theta$ (see also https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5).

Comment: when implementing RAE or RRSE, can you recommend on a reasonable way to avoid `inf`? I thought about using `mean` rather than `sum` and max the denominator with an `epsilon` value

Comment: @ihadanny why do you see inf values?

Comment: when $\theta$ are constant the denominator is 0

Comment: @ihadanny then the error measure does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

A *possible* way would be to normalize the RMSE with the standard deviation of $Y$:

$NRMSE = \frac{RMSE}{\sigma(Y)}$

If this value is larger than 1, you'd obtain a better model by simply generating a random time series of the same mean and standard deviation as $Y$.