# Ways to show how well or badly predicted data reflect observed data

Tags: scatterplot

I have observed rainfall data and would like to know how well they represent the predicted data. My first idea was to show the data on a scatter plot. Plotting x =observed vs y = predicted I set the axis to equal length as well as that the plots are square sizes.

```
t  x   y
1  2.3 3
2  1   1.5
3  4.4 4.8
```

Then I thought I am showing the Pearson correlation coefficient; however I am not sure what are the best ways to show how good my data are.

What other ways exist to assess such data? What would be a sound way to represent the fit of the data and represent it to other? Any creative ideas?

Comment: In practice Pearson correlation might be useful here but in principle it doesn't measure agreement. Consider as a knockdown case, predicted $=$ positive constant $\times$ observed. Here Pearson correlation is identically 1, always, but the larger the constant $>$1, the poorer the fit. Otherwise and more concisely put, Pearson correlation measures linearity, not agreement. Concordance correlation is a measure of agreement.

Comment: Some edits of language, but it's not totally clear what your situation is. Observed versus measured: what's the distinction there? Or is it observed versus predicted, and how were predictions obtained?

Comment: Thanks a lot to all who took their time and giving those good answers. It already made certain things clearer. I do want to show how good the agreement between those two data sets are.

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142585/which-rmse-normalisation-approach-to-use

Answer (score 3):

Plotting the predicted and actual values is always a good idea to see if there is some systematic error in the predictions.

Often people will use a measure of accuracy or error (list copied from [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_14.html). Caveat: I' am author of this page.):

•  Minimum maximum accuracy

•  Mean absolute percent error (MAPE)

•  Root mean square error (RMSE)

•  Normalized root mean square error (NRMSE)

Accuracy measures tend to be reported as a percent or proportion, and so are unit-less. With 1 being a perfect fit.  In my experience, they tend to be high (closer to 1) compared with r-squared values, so you have to be cautious in interpretation.

MAPE is reported as a percent error, so unitless, with 0 being a perfect fit.  RMSE retains the units of the measured variable; again, 0 would be a perfect fit.