# How interpret RMSE figure (Cross Validation)

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

I'm using the Boruta package in R to select the best variables used then for my predictive model. Then I plotted the results from cross validation but I don't understand its meaning.
[image]

How can I Interpret this plot?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @Tim, thanks. In fact, I didn't understand what can I conclude using this figure?? Which are the best variables according to this plot ?? RMSE tell me what exactly??

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/131267/35989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMSE is lowest when 16 features and used. If you use first 16 features then model will have lowest RMS Error.